# Inheriting static values

Tags: php

I'm strongly suspecting I'm designing my overall code wrong, but is it possible to inherit static values?

I have a base class, `BaseModel`, in which I have a `__callStatic` call. `BaseModel` extends into different model types, and in each, I have a `public static $type;` with a string value noting the type. When I call `self::$type` in the `callStatic` call in `BaseModel`, I get back null, which makes sense after the fact. However, I'm not sure then how I can get the type of the class making the call without copying the `callStatic` code into each class (not sure if I can put magic methods in traits?).

Right now, I'm not doing anything fancy:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $params) {
    var_dump(self::$type);
}
```

in `BaseClass`. But I can't figure out how to approach this problem, if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), which could be used with the `static` keyword.

`self` (and also `__CLASS__`) is always evaluated at compile time, so it will always be executed without the knowledge of inheritance and the calling context.

`static` however tries to solve this limitation by evaluating the calling context at runtime.

```
class a {

    public static $foo = "A";

    public static function __callStatic($method, $params) {
        echo static::$foo . "\n";
    }
}

class b extends a {
    public static $foo = "B";
}

a::test();
b::test();
```

Comment: This is late static binding, right? I coincidentally found that page just after creating this question. Sucks when I think of the "right" Google search just after posting a question.